# Enforce that subtype of type matches certain criteria

Tags: typescript

Background: I'm using the JSONObject json-serializable type definition from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117261/5602521, and the method of mapping enums to types from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72705814/5602521, so I have the following:

```
type JSONValue =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | null
  | JSONValue[]
  | { [key: string]: JSONValue };

export interface JSONObject {
  [k: string]: JSONValue;
}

export enum ClientEvent {
  PAGE_VIEW = 'page-view',
  FOO_BUTTON_CLICKED = 'foo-button-clicked',
}

export type ClientEventArgs = {
  [Key in ClientEvent]: {
    [ClientEvent.PAGE_VIEW]: {
      url: string;
    };
    [ClientEvent.FOO_BUTTON_CLICKED]: {
      fooValue: number;
    };
  }[Key];
};

export function logClientEvent<EventType extends ClientEvent>(
  eventType: EventType,
  data: ClientEventArgs[EventType],
): void {}
```

My goal is to use the type system to enforce the following:
**a)** Every enum value in `ClientEvent` must have a corresponding key/value pair in `ClientEventArgs`.
**b)** The type of the value of each key/value pair in `ClientEventArgs` is compatible with the `JSONObject` type.
**c)** When calling `logClientEvent` with a given enum value as the first argument, the type of the second argument must match the type defined in `ClientEventArgs` for that enum value.

My above code achieves a) and c), but not b).

Does anyone know how to enforce that the inner types in `ClientEventArgs` match the `JSONObject` type?

(And sorry for the horrible question title by the way; I'm not even sure how to describe what I'm trying to do here, otherwise I could probably just google it)

EDIT: The following almost works, except that it compiles just fine until you try to call `logClientEvent` for the offending enum value.

```
type ClientEventArgsInner = {
    [ClientEvent.PAGE_VIEW]: {
      url: string;
    };
    [ClientEvent.FOO_BUTTON_CLICKED]: {
      // This should not be allowed by the type system:
      fooValue: () => void;
    };
};

export type ClientEventArgs = {
  [Key in ClientEvent]: ClientEventArgsInner[Key] extends JSONObject ? ClientEventArgsInner[Key] : never;
};

// ...

// Type system only complains about the 'never' when this is uncommented:
// logClientEvent(ClientEvent.FOO_BUTTON_CLICKED, {fooValue: () => {}});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to go about it would be

```ts
type IndexedJSONObjects = {
    [key: string]: JSONObject
}

type ValidateJSONValues<T extends IndexedJSONObjects> = T;

type ClientEventArgsInner = ValidateJSONValues<{
    [ClientEvent.PAGE_VIEW]: {
      url: string;
    };
    [ClientEvent.FOO_BUTTON_CLICKED]: {
      // This should not be allowed by the type system:
      fooValue: () => void;
    };
}>;
```

or, to avoid the long error line,

```
type ClientEventArgsInner = {
    [ClientEvent.PAGE_VIEW]: {
      url: string;
    };
    [ClientEvent.FOO_BUTTON_CLICKED]: {
      // This should not be allowed by the type system:
      fooValue: () => void;
    };
};

type ValidateClientEventArgsInner = ValidateJSONValues<ClientEventArgsInner>
```

none of which are as clean as one would ideally want it to be.

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgygeQHIDUCGAbArtAvAWACgooAfKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMiTz6sBbAIwmpbKhcA9kIwQ09fmywYMU2IlSYcAbQC68gN5QVAawggAXJRoNGa4-GTps0AL4BuIkQgAPMEOrAoDYLwBmaADG0FZICFwAVhBB3pr8esZUdEwWCtbKEE6Eds6Ebh5eUBDsHFAAwhi0JcAAogBuNVDxxFAACgCCAOK1APooAJK1AOpQuFAA5GBojBAAtPXVAO4TADT8AGIICL0AQgCqACqHyL3lADID5QDStQAiY5P+InNcWMDAQvRzQVVB+gATNZEXKEIigSBQAb0AFuCAAsIRaKxCiPFokEh6AxJUypSyKJExYAgvIQ6A2WgAtB+MI2HAUAA8h2Krj8MNR0NhrnhiKiRIoAD5Hoc8gVPN4yRUqjUGjUOtRGKjxhSqTTFHSIIz0TprgYfPQpdV6HVGsa0trMZUjSaagA6To9fpDYbm-gYqBYagYHEpRjZd2ON06K0y03AW1bHYHY6nC5XW53V2td3PIQa4ylHjUf0YwOtOwqXUgNTZOwC7IudziqD+LD0WK0L5QDBCRgh42y40MzvAQ7gaBuNkA1Htm3GgUACn4EDDfcgxh7c4g61aqrQxlHPflipUi-7ahXAEpjPUhJTmqDwf3DaG5QqKND6Lw0UGVJuw-bun1BiMk+6SJ63omL6OYkHm7pvtKHYfpGexHCcSBnJcNz3H+-4APToVAhwABa0KiFA4UIMgAlA9BCN4PBQJgLZLPCgggFAwA4dAkoUCAVAQBwhhBiQqbplAE6HmMQqnpSoFQHmeZXpCKrUhA753oqj7PsqmCUvJtKZIyinGtuD70E+1ACnkQA)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to conditionally omit keys from `ClientEventArgs`:

If you provide a non-matching type, this will cause the definition of `logClientEvent` to throw this exception: `Type 'EventType' cannot be used to index type 'ClientEventArgs'`:

This would look something like

```
export type ClientEventArgs = {
  [Key in ClientEvent as ClientEventArgsInner[Key] extends JSONObject ? Key : never]: ClientEventArgsInner[Key];
};
```

Note that it's important to have this condition in the key rather than the value of the mapped type. According to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23199 , returning `never` in the value will result in the key being present with the type of `never`.
For example, you might get a result like

```
{
  banana: never;
  alice: Apple;
  gala: Apple;
}
```

What we want to do is return `never` in the key, which will actually exclude the key, like

```
{
  alice: Apple;
  gala: Apple;
}
```

We want to exclude this key, because that will cause the aforementioned `Type 'EventType' cannot be used to index type 'ClientEventArgs'` error for bad types (because if the key is excluded, `ClientEventArgs` will be missing at least one key from `ClientEvent`).